# Trigonometry, Using sine rule and area formula.

Tags: trigonometry

Two ships P and Q are observed to be NW and NE respectively of a port A. From a second port B, which is 1km due east of A, the ships P and Q are observed to WNW and NNE respectively. Show that the two ships are approximately 2.61km apart.

This was my interpretation of the question, shown in the image, I couldn't really grasp how the question is related to trigonometry chapter, in other words I don't get the question, although I tried my best drawing it out.

[image: This was my interpretation of the question, shown in the image, I couldn't really grasp how the question is related to trigonometry chapter.]

Comment: What is your geometrical definition of NW, NE and etc.? I can understand for the first two that an angle of $\,45^\circ\,$ must be made with the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining the points, but what's WNW? And why do you get in both cases $\,90^\circ\;$ between both lines of observation?

Comment: If you know angle $QBE$, you can work out all angles in triangle ABQ.  Then the sine rule gives you the other two sides of the triangle.  Then do the same for triangle ABP.

Comment: my diagram is misleading I just realised. I think the NE and other bearings, mean this. Image linked below [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Compass_Rose_English_North.svg/237px-Compass_Rose_English_North.svg.png)_italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Your diagram is fine. Now, just use the compass bearings to get the angles you need to follow @Michael's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that NNW means $68.5^{\circ}$ from the positive horizontal (E), and that WNW means $157.5^{\circ}$ from the positive horizontal.  Use the law of sines to determine that

$$\frac{\sin{22.5^{\circ}}}{1\, \text{km}} = \frac{\sin{112.5^{\circ}}}{|AQ|} $$

Using the half-angle formula for sine, I get that $|AQ| = \sqrt{2}+1$ km.  Further, it should be plain that $|AP| = |AB| = 1$ km by isosceles triangles.  The angle between $AP$ and $AQ$ is $90^{\circ}$, so the distance between the ships is

$$\sqrt{1^2+(\sqrt{2}+1)^2}\, \text{km} = \sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{2}}\, \text{km} \approx 2.613  \, \text{km}$$

Answer (score 0):

consider bqe itself and put BE=d,

further simplifications give distance between the ships=2(1+d).but iam not able to find a simplification for d from your diagram.